# Rails + Bootstrap: Render partial with locals in Bootstrap popover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pass a local variable to my partial when I render it in a Bootstrap popover. Here's what I've got, though I'm pretty sure I'm not rendering the partial correctly in the content_tag.

```
 <%= content_tag :button, type: "button", class: "btn btn-default",
 :data => { container: "body", toggle: "popover", placement: "bottom",
 content: "#{render 'layouts/quick_add_form', :locals => {:code => item1.code}}"} do %>

          button

 <% end %>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Currently the local variable is not being passed to the partial, and so the `:code` attribute is not saved on form submit.

Comment: Please, edit your question – close value for :data key with }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use #{} except in HAML (oh wait, I see #{} is used as regular Ruby string interpolation - I think it will work). Not only that, but when you call `render` on a partial and you want to pass additional values, for some reason (for some versions of Rails), you have to explicitely declare it a partial:

```
render partial: 'layouts/quick_add_form', :locals => {:code => item1.code}
```

That will work, at least in an ERB or HAML.

You should also verify the generated HTML is escaped properly in the data attribute by viewing CTRL-U source in the browser.